# How to clear child layout in android?

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I am developing an android application where I am creating dynamic Images arrow on relative layout. The images are created on a x,y coordinated of the click area of relative layout. Below is the code the I am using for it.

```
presciptionScreenArrowImg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (canSelectMedianStatus == 2) {
                if (event == simulationEvent)
                    return false;
                int action = event.getAction();
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();
                Log.e("onTouchListener", "User touch at X:" + x + " Y:" + y);
                pointerArrow = new ImageView(getApplication());
                pointerArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.pointer);
                pointerArrow.setId(imageArrayTag);
                imageArrayTag++;
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
                params.topMargin = y;
                params.leftMargin = x;
                pointerArrow.setLayoutParams(params);
                presciptionScreenArrowImg.addView(pointerArrow);
                long length = 0;
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                 //                    click(v, x, y);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now, I need is there on button click the last Image drawn should remove first. Basically I need an undo functionality to remove Images as LIFO structure.

Comment: so you can removeview from index where your index would be your layout childcount-1

Comment: @Pavan try that but my all child view get removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let consider presciptionScreenArrowImg is your main layout which contains your all views so for removing

```
int index=presciptionScreenArrowImg.getChildCount();
if(index>0)
presciptionScreenArrowImg.removeViewAt(index-1);
```

from above get count of child and remove last view if you have any problem let me know

Answer (score 0):

Store the views in a Queue, and when you add a new view check if the queue is full. If it is, pop a view from the queue, and call `presciptionScreenArrowImg.remove(poppedView);`

Comment: How to add in Queue can you please explain

Comment: Create a Queue - a type of Collection that is built for LIFO. then after creating the ImageView, add it to the queue. Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Queue.html for details of Queues.

Comment: I have add the view in Image array and try to remove the by Id but dose not work

Comment: Remove the actual view, not by id.